# State is not getting set

Tags: lightning, navigation

I am navigating to another page while clicking on a button, and passing the record Id in the state, however in the url it is not showing,

same is working properly in another org.

getting this in logs:--

> aura_proddebug.js:46891 WARNING: Parameter recordId cannot be used in
>   the URL.

Removing

```
if(state === 'SUCCESS'){
    if(res.getReturnValue() === false){    
        console.log('inside restrict-->');
        component.set('v.restrictAgreementScopeCreation', true);                    
    }
    else {
        console.log('MVK value--->'+component.get('v.isAllowedToManage'));
        if(component.get('v.isAllowedToManage') === true){
            console.log('MVK Inside allowed to manage value--->'+component.get('v.isAllowedToManage'));
            var recId = component.get("v.recordId");
            console.log('console log record Id-->'+recId);
            var navService = component.find("navService");
            var pageReference = {
                type: 'standard__component',
                attributes: {
                    componentName: 'c__LC25_AMSAgreementManagement',
                },
                state: {
                    "recordId" : recId
                }            
            }
            component.set("v.pageReference", pageReference);
            navService.navigate(pageReference);
        }
```

Comment: Console logs says removing..

Comment: Tried changing the name of the parameter as well.

Comment: Could it be this [Add a Namespace Prefix to pageReference.state Properties and Query Parameters](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_namespace_prefix_cruc.htm)?

Comment: Yes , after adding c__ to the parameter it is reflecting in the url.. so while getting the parameter also we have to prefix c__ right???

Comment: Yes they would need to match. Not sure that `c__` is appropriate thought: the aim is to have unique parameters hence the use of a (reserved) namespace. Though maybe `c__` is right for locally created components.